# Is it possible to dismiss the DatePicker's calendar when you tap a date?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I have a basic SwiftUI date picker that shows a calendar widget when tapped:

```swift
DatePicker(
  "Date",
  selection: $date,
  in: ...Date(),
  displayedComponents: [.date]
)
```

[image: expanded calendar]

When you select a date (8th October in the example above), the calendar remains on screen and in order to collapse it, you need to tap outside of it.

Is it possible to automatically collapse it when a date is selected?

Comment: Not by using `DatePicker` alone. You can present the graphical date picker style on tap as a `sheet` or in a `ZStack` and hide when `onChange` the `date`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @lorem-ipsum but in my case a rather ugly hack I posted below seems to be the lesser evil. Firstly, it allows me to use a single, native `DatePicker` view instead of manually building the trigger that would then launch another layer with `GraphicalDatePickerStyle`. Secondly, the expanded calendar is fairly unobtrusive as it nicely sits on top of the content behind it (like an absolutely positioned HTML/CSS layer on top of another layer) and doesn't push the rest of the content down the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up with a rather hacky solution that seems to be doing the job.

Add a `@State` variable that holds the calendar ID:

```swift
@State private var calendarId: Int = 0
```

Chain the `DatePicker` call with `.id`, `.onChange` <s>and .onTapGesture</s> actions:

```swift
DatePicker(
  "Date", selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date]
)
.id(calendarId)
.onChange(of: date) { _ in
  calendarId += 1
})
```

##### Xcode 15 update (November 2023)

In Xcode versions < 15 you might also need an `.onTapGesture` action on the above:

```swift
.onTapGesture {
  calendarId += 1
}
```

But in Xcode 15 this seems to be causing the following crash:

> This UITargetedPreview initializer requires that the view is in a window, but it is not. Either fix that, or use the other initializer that takes a target.

Comment: As of Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15, that .onTapGesture leaves me with an NSInternalInconsistencyException. However, leaving that out works fine for me.

Comment: @jason-farnsworth, I haven't been able to reproduce this exception in Xcode 13.2.1.

Comment: Trying this in XCode 14/iOS 16 and it no longer works, getting a `NSInternalInconsistencyException`

Comment: This is working fine for me in XCode 14 / iOS 15 and 16 though I did remove the .OnTapGesture that didn't seem to have any impact on the result.

Comment: For note I am using and have only tested with the CompactDatePickerStyle(). It may not work as well with others.

Comment: This is working fine for me in XCode 14.2.

Comment: Use `.id(date)` then you don't need the `calendarId` property.

Comment: Great suggestion @Al Priest but it doesn't seem to be working in iOS versions older than 17. I've tried it in simulators running 15.5 and 16.4.

Answer (score 5):

@chris.kobrzak provided a good direction, and I ended up solving this with:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var calendarId: UUID = UUID()
    @State var someday: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Day", selection: $someday, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .labelsHidden()
                .id(calendarId)
                .onChange(of: whatday) { _ in
                    calendarId = UUID()
                }
            AnotherView(someday)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The removal of `onTapGesture` breaks the expected behaviour - the calendar widget no longer gets collapsed when you tap a date in my app. I'm also not convinced with changing the type of `calendarId` from `Int` to `UUID` as generating IDs is a more expensive operation. Still, I like the shorthand notation for the `onChange` call (no need for the `perform` label).

Comment: @ChrisKobrzak I felt better about UUID knowing you could eventually overflow Int... although that is extremely unlikely. I'm not sure why we are seeing a difference with onTapGesture. I'm hoping to dig into that some more.

Comment: this is also not working any updated answer for this?

Comment: Can someone explain why this is hiding the `DatePicker`, I can't seam to wrap my head around why this "works" as a tacky solution.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov The .id is for the DatePicker 'view', not for the DatePicker specifically so to speak. When you change the .id of a view you basically reset it. This explains it better. https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/

Comment: when I try to change the month it gets dismissed which's very weird from the user's perspective

Answer (score 1):

This is just an updated answer following @Chris Kobrzak as above.

I am using XCode 14.1 and iOS 15+ and 16+ (iPad and iPhone) and it seems to work without error today in Nov 2022.

I have seen some folk using the same .id() method complain that it doesn’t work.

I haven’t tested this but note that I am using the CompactDatePickerStyle(), maybe it doesn’t work the same on other styles.

The reason this hack works is the .id() is for the ‘view’ (DatePicker being a view). When you change the id of a view you basically reset it (in this case closing the DatePicker).

There is a good explanation about .id() here: https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/

Why this isn’t built into the control seems rather a joke but hey…

Note I have ripped the following out of a real App. I've edited it in a dumb text editor to post on here so there may be some silly syntax errors and odd remnants of the original code.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FooView: View {
    
    @Published var dateOfBirth: Date = Date()
   
    @State private var datePickerId: Int = 0
    
    private var dateOfBirthRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let dateFrom = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -160, to: Date())!
        let dateTo: Date = Date()
        return dateFrom...dateTo
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Date of Birth")
                    .offset(y: -36)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                    .scaleEffect(0.9, anchor: .leading)
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $dateOfBirth,
                    in: dateOfBirthRange,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
                .labelsHidden()
                .id(datePickerId)
                .onChange(of: dateOfBirth) { _ in
                    datePickerId += 1
                }

            }
            .padding(.top, 24)
            .animation(.default, value: "")

        }
        
    }
    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and put a `.graphical` `DatePicker` in my own `popover`. The only downside is on iPhone popovers currently show as sheets but that's ok.

```
struct DatePickerPopover: View {
    @State var showingPicker = false
    @State var oldDate = Date()
    @Binding var date: Date
    let doneAction: () -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(date, format:.dateTime.year())
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        .onTapGesture {
            showingPicker.toggle()
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showingPicker, attachmentAnchor: .point(.center)) {
            NavigationStack {
                DatePicker(selection: $date
                           , displayedComponents: [.date]){
                    
                }
               .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
               .toolbar {
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                       Button("Cancel") {
                           date = oldDate
                           showingPicker = false
                       }
                   }
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                       Button("Done") {
                           doneAction()
                           showingPicker = false
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
            
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            oldDate = date
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePicker(
  "Date", selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date]
)
.id(calendarId)
.onChange(of: date, perform: { _ in
  calendarId += 1
})
```

You won't need onTapGesture since it already recognise your date is changed

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue until SwiftUI brings some new update I prefer to use the following solution with `.popOver` view.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDate: Date = .now
    @State var showCalendar = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Display size: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)") // For debuging purpose
                showCalendar = true // Presenting the Calendar
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                Text(selectedDate, style: .date)
            })
            .popover(isPresented: $showCalendar) {
                DatePicker(
                    "Select date",
                    selection: $selectedDate,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 365, height: 365) // Check the explanation part
                .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover) // It will show popOver in iPhones too
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedDate) { _, _ in
                showCalendar = false // Dismisses the calendar
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanaiton of `frame(width: 365, height: 365)`**

Understanding this part is very important to use this solution. The smallest device I want to support for my app is IPhone SE (3rd Gen), which has screen width 375 (You can print as I did in the button action, please check)

So If I want my calendar to fit in the smallest device I made the frame size height and width equals to 365. Also the calendar view itself is of shape square so the height and width should be equal (I don't have any prove for this, it is my observation)

**Note:** Where you show the calendar you need to make sure that there is enough space in height and width to show the calendar view frame size (365 in my case). In most of the cases you don't need to worry about these things, these corner cases may arise only in small devices.

**Output simulation video**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The answers didn't work for my case, maybe because in my case the `sheet` has more views not just the `DatePicker`. Posting this in case some might need it:

```
// omitted variables declaration...
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        // omitted other views...
        DatePicker(
            "Select date",
            selection: Binding<Date>(
                get: { self.selectedDate },
                set: {
                    self.selectedDate = $0
                    self.dismiss()
                }
            ),
            displayedComponents: [.date]
        )
        .labelsHidden()
        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution for this is:

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date])
.id(date.timeIntervalSince1970)
```