# Dismiss SwiftUI DatePicker when user taps on already selected date

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker

I want the user to select a date in the past by presenting a SwiftUI **DatePicker**. The date binding is set to today's date.

Now, I want the user to be able to select **today's date**. But when the user taps on the already selected date, the DatePicker is not dismissed. It only is dismissed when the user taps on a date that was not already selected. So in my case I want to dismiss the DatePicker when the user taps on 13.

[image: DatePicker]

Is there a way to dismiss the DatePicker when the user taps on the preselected date?

Here is how I use the DatePicker:

```
struct DatePickerView: View {
    @Binding var date: Date

    var body: some View {
        DatePicker(
            "Select Date",
            selection: $date,
            in: ...Date(),
            displayedComponents: [.date]
        )
        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .padding(.horizontal, 40)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516600/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-datepickers-calendar-when-you-tap-a-date#comment122877274_69516600

Comment: Thanks for the comment @loremipsum The linked question does not help me though. My DatePicker is dismissed when the user selects any date except the already selected date. So everything is fine when the user selects another date. Only when the user taps on the already selected date, nothing happens. I want to dismiss the DatePicker in that case.

Comment: @joern did you manage to know when the user selects the already selected date?
I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @N.Fredman Unfortunately not

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and put a `.graphical` `DatePicker` in my own `popover`. The only downside is on iPhone popovers currently show as sheets which is an annoying inconsistency. Now you can control the popover presentation however you like and even have cancel/done actions.

```
struct DatePickerPopover: View {
    @State var showingPicker = false
    @State var oldDate = Date()
    @Binding var date: Date
    let doneAction: () -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(date, format:.dateTime.year())
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        .onTapGesture {
            showingPicker.toggle()
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showingPicker, attachmentAnchor: .point(.center)) {
            NavigationStack {
                DatePicker(selection: $date
                           , displayedComponents: [.date]){
                    
                }
               .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
               .toolbar {
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                       Button("Cancel") {
                           date = oldDate
                           showingPicker = false
                       }
                   }
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                       Button("Done") {
                           doneAction()
                           showingPicker = false
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
            
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            oldDate = date
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it! Your suggestion works, but in my case I cannot not use it because it would change the look of the UI and unfortunately my client would not accept that design change. I will leave this question as open, because as good as your suggestion is, it does not solve my problem. I hope that is okay with you.

Comment: @malhal did you figured out how to deal with this?

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution.
From iOS 16.4 you can show popOver to iPhones also with this line of code:

`.presentationCompactAdaptation((.popover))`

But the problem is the graphical calendar does not actually fit inside the small popOver in iPhone.